# Save Japanese characters into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unicode, cjk

I am using PHP for executing a MySQL update sentence with Spanish, English and Japanese characters.

But i'm not able to save Japanese characters into the database.  How should I proceed?

> Database has utf8_general_ci collation.

```
$strSQL = "UPDATE table SET value = '" . addslashes($strValue) . "'";
$strSQL = utf8_decode($strSQL);
mysqli_query($cnn, $strSQL);
```

---

With `addslashes` I can get apostrophes to be saved into the database.

With `utf8_decode` I can get Spanish characters to be saved into the database.

Comment: You absolutely should not be using `addslashes`, use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You also should not use `utf8_decode`, you need to make sure you are using UTF-8 as your database and page encoding. You can find information on how to use UTF-8 in PHP online (phptherightway.com)

Comment: If you still have trouble after implementing the changes suggested by Andrea and and Max Base, see if [_this_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why you proccess `utf8_decode()` the sql query?

> Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php for details about **utf8_decode()**

---

#### You have to check a few things.

Whether there is a problem in your database and tables Or in your PHP script.

#### Database :

```
CREATE DATABASE test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

#### Table Charset :

```
CREATE TABLE test.table
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

#### Connection :

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

E.g :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","test_db");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

OR

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","test_db");
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");
```

#### Configure the encoding charset of server :

> With PHPMyAdmin , Choose UTF-8 when you login.

**PHP Script :**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

**Apache Config (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) :**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**Apache .htaccess file :**

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
```

**PHP Config (/etc/php.ini) :**

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

**MySQL Config (/etc/my.cnf ) :**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-client = utf8
```

#### User values :

> e.g : `$_GET` , `$_POST`

You can use `mb_convert_encoding()` for convert your strings to **UTF-8**.

---

Useful Links :

- [PHP inserting Japanese string to utf8 table as something else, but still reads it successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034688/php-inserting-japanese-string-to-utf8-table-as-something-else-but-still-reads-i)
- http://es2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php
- [Select MySQL rows with Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360544/select-mysql-rows-with-japanese-characters)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp
- [PHP mysql charset utf8 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068616/php-mysql-charset-utf8-problems)
- https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-cjk.html
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24742133/How-to-insert-a-japanese-character-into-mysql-database.html